# Making an ldap_bind in PHP 8.2.4

Tags: php, xampp, ldap

I am creating a ldap_bind using XAMPP 8.2.4. I am using the same commands that in the PHP Manual on my http site (not https). I have the CA Cert installed on Personal Computer cert store of the web server. Server webpage is an http site.

```
 <?php
  $adServer = "ldaps://DC01.DOMAIN.NET";
  $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
  $ldaprdn = 'DOMAIN' . "\\" . $user;
  ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
  ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
  ldap_get_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err);
  $bind = ldap_bind($ldap,$ldaprdn,$password);
  echo "ldap_error: $err";
  if ($bind) {
    echo "Bind Good";
  }
  else {
    echo "Bind Bad";
  }  
?>
```

I am getting the following for an error:

```
Can't connect LDAP server
ldap_error: error:16000069:STORE routines::unregister scheme
```

I have tested ldap_connect and there is no problem reaching the server. So what is preventing the bind from working? Does the site need to be SSL as of PHP 8.2.4? I know as of 8.1.0 the ldap_connect  was made but it was a transparent change.

**UPDATE**: Added SSL security to the site so it now loads at https:// but still getting the same ldap_error

Comment: 1. Get rid of the `@` [error suppression operator] from `@ldap_bind()` as it will suppress the error message that is probably trying to tell you what is wrong. 2. Never use the error suppression operator unless you have literally _no_ other option. Fix errors, don't paper over them.

Comment: @Sammitch oh ok thanks. It is saying it can't connect to the ldap server. Even though I can ping it not sure why it says it can't connect.

Comment: My money is on your LDAP server using old SSL modes/ciphers that the new server no longer supports or otherwise refuses to use.

Comment: @Sammitch not sure why it would be using different modes since they are the same OS.

Comment: Are they literally on the same server? Are they using the same TLS library as a dependency? If so have you restarted the LDAP service since the supposed upgrade? Did you only upgrade PHP and not whatever is running your LDAP? Did you actually _verify_ any of this, or are you just being contrarian?

Comment: @Sammitch No this is a new webserver. I have enabled the extension=ldap extension in XAMPP. The DC is the same. No change there. Only difference between the the servers is one is running XAMPP 8.0.0.0 and the new one is running 8.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the fix for it. Thanks to @Wes Wakeman for this post:

[XAMPP 7.0.4 PHP 7 LDAPS Connection can't bind LDAP works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141289/xampp-7-0-4-php-7-ldaps-connection-cant-bind-ldap-works-fine)

Even though XAMPP is not running on the same drive as the C drive the ldap.conf  needs to be on C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\ with the files. I am going to ask Apachefriends how I can move it.